# How to identify just the year of DateTime in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a number of news articles coming from our CMS that are displayed on a webpage. Currently the page displays articles from the past 3 months (based on date posted) using this piece of code.

```
rptNews.DataSource = NewsAndEventUtility.News.Where(n => n.DatePosted >= DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3));
```

Now I would like to create an archived news page that only displays from a particular year (2012), but I can't seem to get the code right...

```
rptNews.DataSource = NewsAndEventUtility.News.Where(n => n.DatePosted = DateTime.Year.Equals(2012));
```

or

```
rptNews.DataSource = NewsAndEventUtility.News.Where(n => n.DatePosted = DateTime.Year(2012));
```

Neither of these work. I am trying to understand how to identify the year of the instance and compare it to a specific year. Perhaps this is not possible with DateTime or I'm just thinking of it wrong.

Comment: **How** doesn't it work? What happens? What LINQ provider are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Which type is `n.DatePosted`? If it has a member `Year` as well, you can use:

```
rptNews.DataSource = NewsAndEventUtility.News.Where(n => n.DatePosted.Year == 2012);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
 .Where(n => n.DatePosted.Year == 2012);
```

Also, your code looks to be incorrectly using `=` instead of `==` in the where clause?

```
rptNews.DataSource = NewsAndEventUtility.News.Where(n => n.DatePosted = DateTime.Year.Equals(2012));
```

should have been:

```
rptNews.DataSource = NewsAndEventUtility.News.Where(n => n.DatePosted == DateTime.Year.Equals(2012));
                                                                   ----^
```